# Governance token and Utility token

Tags: tokens, cryptoeconomics

Lately I began to learn about web3 technology, cryptocurrency, DAO and etc.
I have read some whitepapers of XtoEarn projects and almost of them have governance token and utility token.
I looked them up, then I think I understood their big concents.
However I don't get why a lot of projects have both of them. Because some utility token seem to have the vote right (but its power isn't critical).

Does anyone know why XtoEarn projects don't like to have only one type of token?

Sorry for the basic question and thank you in advance!
Please let me know if there are better places I should ask this.

Comment: 99% of the projects out there would function perfectly without a token. The tokens  in themselves are just cash grabs for project owners and early investors. Apart from that, this question isnt really well suited for this forum, we mostly talk about technical stuff here :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Forgive my silly question.